# Why Game returns back to menu automatically in between levels?

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game using andEngine. Game is running fine,but after few levels,it returns to menu screen automatically. The logcat is as follows. What might be the problem?

> 08-03 11:53:10.556: ERROR/ActivityThread(302): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings 08-03 11:53:10.556:
>   ERROR/ActivityThread(302): Failed to find provider info for
>   com.google.settings 08-03 11:53:10.576: INFO/ActivityThread(302):
>   Publishing provider com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider:
>   com.android.globalsearch.SuggestionProvider 08-03 11:53:10.726:
>   INFO/ActivityThread(302): Publishing provider
>   com.android.globalsearch.stats: com.android.globalsearch.StatsProvider
>   08-03 11:53:10.726: INFO/ActivityThread(302): Publishing provider
>   contacts;call_log: com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider
>   08-03 11:53:10.776: WARN/ActivityManager(51): Unable to start service
>   Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService
>   cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService }: not found
>   08-03 11:53:10.776: WARN/AccountMonitor(302): Couldn't connect to
>   Intent { act=android.accounts.IAccountsService
>   cmp=com.google.android.googleapps/.GoogleLoginService } (Missing
>   service?)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you game is trying to log in the user to their Google account, but that is failing.  So two follow up questions: 
1. are you trying to use google services in your game?
2. Is this error occuring on the emulator on a build of android that does not include the Google APIs?

Comment: Yes.. This error is occuring on the emulator on a build of android that does not include the Google APIs..

Comment: Are you firing an intent for an account service or a login? That seems to be triggering a call to the google account service, which is not installed.  Test the app on an emulator that DOES include teh google api's and see if the error goes away.

Comment: I changed my version n tried. Now I'm getting this error..          08-08 10:10:39.203: ERROR/InputDispatcher(60): channel '406c6df0 org.bg.demo/org.bg.demo.BgDemoActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Well, I'm not at all sure where that is coming from, but my guess is you are using some code from a demo that you need to customize before running. does that package name mean anything to you? IT sounds like placeholder: org.bg.demo.BgDemoActivity

Comment: Yeah.. that is the activity which I'm trying to run. Am able to play some 2-3 levels..Later I'm getting this Error.Any idea about this problem?